# Skip "more" option for listing all errors while compiling in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, compilation, cmd, batch-processing

I am compilation batch file inside a batch file which fill execute all the c-files in the current directory. If build success it goes fine. If it build failed with few errors, then also goes fine but only problem when building errors with more errors than display. By displaying ----more----- message it is halting and not moving to next commands in batch file.

```
D3LUY2V.c:1682: case label not within a switch statement
D3LUY2V.c:1685: case label not within a switch statement
D3LUY2V.c:1699: case label not within a switch statement
D3LUY2V.c:1703: case label not within a switch statement
D3LUY2V.c:1706: case label not within a switch statement
D3LUY2V.c:1709: case label not within a switch statement
D3LUY2V.c:1712: case label not within a switch statement
D3LUY2V.c:1715: case label not within a switch statement
D3LUY2V.c:1718: case label not within a switch statement
D3LUY2V.c:1724: case label not within a switch statement
D3LUY2V.c:1730: case label not within a switch statement
D3LUY2V.c:1736: case label not within a switch statement
D3LUY2V.c:1744: case label not within a switch statement
D3LUY2V.c:1945: case label not within a switch statement
D3LUY2V.c:1948: case label not within a switch statement
D3LUY2V.c:1966: case label not within a switch statement
D3LUY2V.c:1970: case label not within a switch statement
D3LUY2V.c:1974: case label not within a switch statement
D3LUY2V.c:1978: case label not within a switch statement
D3LUY2V.c:1981: case label not within a switch statement
D3LUY2V.c:1984: case label not within a switch statement
D3LUY2V.c:1987: case label not within a switch statement
D3LUY2V.c:1993: case label not within a switch statement
D3LUY2V.c:1999: case label not within a switch statement
D3LUY2V.c:2005: case label not within a switch statement
D3LUY2V.c:2013: case label not within a switch statement
-- MORE --
```

Here is the batch file, i am using where mk123456 is the batch which is compiling the source files. but i cant edit that batch file. This mk123456 batch file is displaying the -- more -- if the errors are more as shown above.

```
@CD %CD%
@FOR %%* IN (.) DO SET cdir=%%~n*
SET cpath = %cdir%
@ECHO **********Copying SourceFiles From Src****************
@XCOPY /Q .\Src\*.c     /Y
@XCOPY /Q .\Src\*.h     /Y
@ECHO **********Compling %cdir% *******************
CALL mk123456
DEL mk123456.bat
```

Here is the screen shot of the error in the batch file where it is halting the batch file. Is there any option to skip this message in the batch file and go to end like manually if we enter "Q" means it will skip to the end of error message. How to do in the batch file to skip this message which is halting the batch file executing.

Comment: It would help if you show the batch file. You could try `Echo Q|whatever|more`

Comment: We need to see the batch file to help.

Comment: Hi, I have edited the question and added the batch file code...

Comment: Change the `call` line to this `:: call mk123456` - do the more prompts disappear?  And in `set cpath = %cdir%` remove the spaces.  They are being included in the variable name and content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are able to delete mk123456.bat, then I don't see why you cannot edit it.

But I believe I have a solution for you. I'm assuming your mk123456.bat script is piping output to MORE. If so, then you can prevent it from pausing by changing your CALL statement as follows:

```
CALL mk123456 | findstr "^"
```